# Problem with installing phpmyadmin to VPS Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apache, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, vps

I want to install phpMyAdmin to Ubuntu on VPS. I tried this commands in this order:

1.Check for updates:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

2.Install phpMyAdmin + apache2 utils:

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin apache2-utils
```

3.Include phpmyadmin config in apache2 config:

```
nano /etc/apach2/apache2.conf
```

After:

```
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

I put this:

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

On `www.mydomain.com/phpmyadmin` I found a text:

[This is the link to my VPS domain](http://31.220.60.214/phpmyadmin/)

Comment: Pls I need help!

Comment: Probably I need to post this question on ask-ubuntu, no?

Comment: Looks like php is not intalled or not configured...

Comment: help me please!

Comment: Well, install php. We cannot help you with that.

Comment: I have php installed!
php -v:

Comment: `PHP 7.0.32-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.32-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies`

Comment: That is the command line version of php. To use it as a module inside the http server environment you need that module, not the command line version. Please check if that is installed too. Actually I would expect that to be a requirement for packages like `phpmyadmin`, but maybe that is optional, since there are alternatives. To get things going however you should install that module. The package name is probably something like `libapache2-mod-php7` or similar.